# Angular 5 HttpClient Path Variable

Tags: angular, rest, angular5

I'm developing an Angular Client for a REST API.

My api exposes URL like:

```
https://server.com/users/detail/3
```

Where 3 is a parameter.

I try to generate a path variable using Angular Client but I have not been able. I try

```
getUser(username: string) {
const options = {
  params: new HttpParams().set('username', username)
};

return this.http.get<User>('detail/{username}', options); }
```

But the result isn't correct.
Can someone help me?

*EDIT*

After I try the solutions, it doesn't still work. If

```
 getUser(username: string) {
const options = {
  params: new HttpParams().set('username', username)
};

const resource = 'detail/' + username;
return this.http.get<any>(resource);  }
```

This solution seems me too poor, Has Angular HttpClient any solution for this?

Comment: How does the httpClient get to know the target url if you don't specify it fully?

Comment: Because I’m using an interceptor to externalize this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because use http.get your parameter should be inserted in the URL:

```
getUser(username: string): void {
   let url = `https://server.com/users/detail/${username}`;
   this.http.get< User >(url)  
     //if api returns any data
     .subscribe((returnObject: User) => {
       //returned data
       //remember that this segment will be returned asynchronously
       //for example: callback(returnObject);
     }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
       //if error
       //for example: errorCallback(error)
     })
}
```

If you want set HttpParams you should use this.http.post - of course if the server supports the post instead of get.

Comment: I would surely hope there is a better built-in Angular or TypeScript way of providing URL path parameters. The problem with this particular way is that it is just direct string concatenation with no special character replacements. If your username happens to be `my/name?is=slim&shady` you don't actually call the endpoint correctly (for most backend frameworks). You will either call the `/users/detail/` endpoint with name `my` discarding the following URL content, OR the `/users/detail/my/name` endpoint resulting in a 404 (or different) error.

Comment: fully agree with @Snackoverflow here

in addition for all who use this approach.
you should wrap the value for the path variable with `encodeURIComponent()` for the sake of security

Answer (score 2):

Your second attempt is close, but you need to use a dollar sign and backticks instead of single-quotes to get the string interpolation to work:

```
return this.http.get<User>(`detail/${username}`, options); }
```

Comment: I am not seeing this work in my own attempts either. This was dirt simple in AngularJS but in Angular there seems to be no documentation about this for `httpClient`. Your syntax did not work for me.

Comment: Yes, you are correct - it was a typo, which I fixed just now. String interpolation requires backticks, and the parameter must be surrounded by curly braces and a leading dollar sign. See the updated answer.

Comment: Just to clarify, `username` would be provided in the HttpParams for the request?

Comment: No, in this case, it's part of the path.

Comment: Now I'm confused - what exactly is `options`? I want to dynamically provide a path segment to be filled in later. In AngularJS you would define 'myapy/resources/:id' and then when invoked with params, the 'id' param would be put there in the path...